# How to add array and data columns to datatable in C#

Tags: datatable, crystal-reports

I'm using Datatable as data source of crystal report , but loading reports is very slow because of amount of data is big , let empdepttbl is the datatable , i'm using this loop to set data to the rows of datatable

```
for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            empdepttbl.Rows.Add(new Object[]{dt.Rows[i][7].ToString(),month[mon],dt.Rows[i][2].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][3].ToString(),dt.Rows[i][4].ToString(),string.Format("{0:#,###0}",t)});
        }
```

dt is the Datatable which contains data that selected from database ..

so, how can I setting data directly without using loop ?

Comment: what is (dt) where come ?
and why get data from dt and set to empdepttbl ?

Comment: dt is datatable stores data selected from database, empdepttbl has fields more that dt, as you see , i'm setting data from variables and dt to empdepttbl..

Comment: why no store desired data direct in dt ?
Select ( Required Data ) and set in dt !

Comment: I want to do that excalty , but how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This and dont forget mark as answer if work

```
foreach(var item in dt)
{
empdepttbl.Rows.Add(new Object[]{item [7].ToString(),month[mon],item [2].ToString(),item [3].ToString(),item [4].ToString(),string.Format("{0:#,###0}",t)});
}
```

And you Can Use the dt direct in crystal report data source

Comment: change in code what you want to insert i don't know what you datatables contain